# How to push objects in AngularJS between ngRepeat arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to build a very simple list app, where I can create an ng-repeat item list and then push a selected item into another ng-repeat list. Although my problem seems to be very simple I wasn't able to find a proper solution yet.

**So here's the simplified markup:**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
 <div id="MyApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div id="AddItem">
         <h3>Add Item</h3>

        <input value="1" type="number" placeholder="1" ng-model="itemAmount">
        <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Name of Item" ng-model="itemName">
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="addItem()">Add to list</button>
    </div>
    <!-- begin: LIST OF CHECKED ITEMS -->
    <div id="CheckedList">
         <h3>Checked Items: {{getTotalCheckedItems()}}</h3>

         <h4>Checked:</h4>

        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in checked" class="item-checked">
                <td><b>amount:</b> {{item.amount}} -</td>
                <td><b>name:</b> {{item.name}} -</td>
                <td> 
                   <i>this item is checked!</i>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- end: LIST OF CHECKED ITEMS -->
    <!-- begin: LIST OF UNCHECKED ITEMS -->
    <div id="UncheckedList">
         <h3>Unchecked Items: {{getTotalItems()}}</h3>

         <h4>Unchecked:</h4>

        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="item-unchecked">
                <td><b>amount:</b> {{item.amount}} -</td>
                <td><b>name:</b> {{item.name}} -</td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="toggleChecked($index)">check item</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- end: LIST OF ITEMS -->
  </div>
</body>
```

**And here goes my AngularJS Script:**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("mainController",

function ($scope) {

// Item List Arrays
$scope.items = [];
$scope.checked = [];

// Add a Item to the list
$scope.addItem = function () {

    $scope.items.push({
        amount: $scope.itemAmount,
        name: $scope.itemName
    });

    // Clear input fields after push
    $scope.itemAmount = "";
    $scope.itemName = "";

};

// Add Item to Checked List and delete from Unchecked List
$scope.toggleChecked = function (item, index) {
    $scope.checked.push(item);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
};

// Get Total Items
$scope.getTotalItems = function () {
    return $scope.items.length;
};

// Get Total Checked Items
$scope.getTotalCheckedItems = function () {
    return $scope.checked.length;
};
});
```

So when I click the button, my toggleChecked() function triggers and it actually pushes something into my checked list. However, it seems to be just an empty object. The function can't get the actual item that I want to push.

What am I doing wrong here?

NOTE: Checking items via click on a button is intended. I don't want to use checkboxes in this case.

You can see the working model here: http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/1/

Cheers,
Norman

Answer (score 35, accepted):

change your method to:

```
$scope.toggleChecked = function (index) {
    $scope.checked.push($scope.items[index]);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/3/)**

Answer (score 7):

You'd be much better off using the same array with both lists, and creating angular filters to achieve your goal.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters

Rough, untested code follows:

```
appModule.filter('checked', function() {
    return function(input, checked) {
        if(!input)return input;
        var output = []
        for (i in input){
            var item = input[i];
            if(item.checked == checked)output.push(item);
        }
        return output
    }
});
```

and the view (i added an "uncheck" button too)

```
<div id="AddItem">
     <h3>Add Item</h3>

    <input value="1" type="number" placeholder="1" ng-model="itemAmount">
    <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Name of Item" ng-model="itemName">
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add to list</button>
</div>
<!-- begin: LIST OF CHECKED ITEMS -->
<div id="CheckedList">
     <h3>Checked Items: {{getTotalCheckedItems()}}</h3>

     <h4>Checked:</h4>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | checked:true" class="item-checked">
            <td><b>amount:</b> {{item.amount}} -</td>
            <td><b>name:</b> {{item.name}} -</td>
            <td> 
               <i>this item is checked!</i>
               <button ng-click="item.checked = false">uncheck item</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- end: LIST OF CHECKED ITEMS -->
<!-- begin: LIST OF UNCHECKED ITEMS -->
<div id="UncheckedList">
     <h3>Unchecked Items: {{getTotalItems()}}</h3>

     <h4>Unchecked:</h4>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | checked:false" class="item-unchecked">
            <td><b>amount:</b> {{item.amount}} -</td>
            <td><b>name:</b> {{item.name}} -</td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="item.checked = true">check item</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- end: LIST OF ITEMS -->
```

Then you dont need the toggle methods etc in your controller

Comment: I thought about something similar at first, but I fear that my controller would get too messy as the project becomes more complex. For instance, if I would add another state besides "checked" and "unchecked" and reuse items with different states in other views, things would get more difficult. Keeping my items sorted in multiple controllers will probably keep my code more clean and I'm more flexible later on in the project.

Answer (score -6):

Try this one also...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to join two arrays.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var hege = [{
        1: "Cecilie",
        2: "Lone"
      }];
      var stale = [{
        1: "Emil",
        2: "Tobias"
      }];
      var hege = hege.concat(stale);
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = hege;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = stale;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Avoid javascript in the dom with AngularJS.