# Data displayed with ngrepeat not passing to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an AngularFire object ([$firebaseObject()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject)) named `ctrl.data`, which ng-repeat displays. In the markup generated by ng-repeat I have a button which runs a function when clicked. I would like to pass information from the item that ng-repeat used to fill out the markup to a function.

My data on Firebase is structured as such*:

[image]
*all spaces have been removed from object names

Markup

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ctrl.data track by $index">
    {{data.name}}, {{data.lvl}} ...
    <input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.addToBook(data.classes, data.comp, data.csttime, ...)" value="Add!">
</div>
```

The function

```
ctrl.addToBook = function (classes, comp, csttime, ...) {
      ctrl.book.push({
        classes: classes, comp: comp, csttime: csttime ...
      });
```

When the function runs it is pushing:

```
{classes: undefined, comp: undefined, csttime: undefined...}
```

I've also tried

- Replacing passing the argument `data` and pushing the entire object
  but I'm told what I'm pushing is undefined. Example:
  `ng-click="addToBook(data)"` and `function(toBePassed)
  {data.book.push(toBePassed);}`
- Putting {{ }} around each argument,
  which Angular didn't want render. Error: [$parse:syntax]
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?... Later it
  references to the button. Following the link gives: `Error:
  $parse:syntax / Syntax Error: Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column
  {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].` Which I don't know
  how to interpret.

What do I need to do to pass the information to the function, or have the function know what to push?

Each object that is being iterated by ng-repeat has a name property which matches the name of the object, so the name of the objects could be removed and I could use an array instead of an object. Would restructuring the data so it's an array make this easier, because I could then reference to an Id? If so I believe I would be in a similar situation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098159/how-to-push-objects-in-angularjs-between-ngrepeat-arrays), but would prefer to avoid using Id's.

Another alternative would be giving each object a method which pushes the needed data. Would this be a better approach? I'm still feeling rather new to angular but I think [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and [$firebaseObject.$extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) would be where to start, is that correct?

---

More information:

I've double checked the contents of ctrl.data. Each entry has data.__.classes, so I don't think the issue is from missing parameters. This is
console.log(ctrl.data)'s output.

```
$$conf: Object
$id: null
$priority: null
AnimalFriendship: Object
    classes: "Bard, Cleric (Nature), Druid, Ranger"
    comp: "V, S, M (a morsel of food)"
    csttime: "1 action"
    desc: "-Long description-"
    duration: "24 hours"
    lvl: 1
    name: "Animal Friendship"
    range: "30 feet"
    ritual: false
    school: "Enchantment"
    __proto__: Object
-Many more objects which have the same properties as above-
__proto__: Object
    $$error: ...
    $$notify: ...
    $bindTo: ...
    $destroy: ...
    $loaded: ...
    $ref: ...
    $remove: ...
    $save: ...
    $watch: ...
    forEach: ...
    __proto__: Object
```

However console.log(ctrl.data.AnimalFriendship) outputs undefined.

---

**tldr;**
I'm unable to access the objects which ng-repeat are accessing, and therefore cannot pass the information that each iteration is dealing with into a function. Changing from an AngularFire Object to AngularFire Array may need to be the answer, and careful planning to avoid [possible $index problems](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/).

Comment: If this is still a problem, put up a plunkr which shows the problem and I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `data` does not have the required parameters - so `data.classes` etc are undefined. The object `data` itself is defined though; if it wasn't, an error would be thrown earlier on. Try double checking what you're iterating over (ie. `ctrl.data`) and if the object of the iteration actually has the parameters you are looking for.

Comment: I've added the contents of console.log(ctrl.data) but cannot access children of ctrl.data, such as ctrl.data.AnimalFriendship. The parameters I'm looking for exist on Firebase, and I can see them, but cannot seem to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your controller code (assuming it's named 'ctrl'?), I can't say for sure, but I think you're looking for

```
$scope.addToBook = function (...) {
    ...
};
```

And then call your method like so: `ng-click="addToBook..."`

You should be setting your data on $scope as well, so `$scope.data = []`

Then it would be referenced as just `data`, not `ctrl.data` in the mark-up.

Comment: I've been using the `__ = this;` method. In this case `ctrl = this;` My function is `ctrl.addToBook = function (arguments) {ctrl.book.push({property: argument ... });` The ng-click is placed on a button which appears with each iteration of ng-repeat. My goal is to pass the information which ng-repeat is creating, ex. `{{data.lvl}}` would be passed as an argument `data.lvl`. I'm hesitant to keep adding more code, but is there any code which should be added to the question?